Lexing Issue in ANTLR4 Grammar for Fortran 2018: Token Misclassification
I am developing a Fortran 2018 grammar in ANTLR4 using the ISO standard. I am encountering an issue during the lexing phase with some of the lexer rules. Specifically, certain keywords are being misclassified. Below is the minimal grammar demonstrating the problem:
Grammar: FortranTestF18.g4
grammar FortranTestF18;

//LEXER RULES

LINE_COMMENT : '!' .*? '\r'? '\n' -> skip ;

BLOCK_COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

PROGRAM: 'PROGRAM' | 'Program' | 'program';

END: 'END' | 'End' | 'end';

COMMA: ',';

LPAREN: '(';

RPAREN: ')';

ASTERIK: '*';

NONE: 'NONE' | 'None' | 'none';

IMPLICIT: 'IMPLICIT' | 'Implicit' | 'implicit';

FORMAT: 'FORMAT' | 'Format' | 'format';

PLUS: '+';

// R765 binary-constant -> B ' digit [digit]... ' | B " digit [digit]... "
BINARYCONSTANT: B APOSTROPHE DIGIT+ APOSTROPHE | B QUOTE DIGIT+ QUOTE;

// R766 octal-constant -> O ' digit [digit]... ' | O " digit [digit]... "
OCTALCONSTANT: O APOSTROPHE DIGIT+ APOSTROPHE | O QUOTE DIGIT+ QUOTE;

//R0003 RepChar
APOSTROPHEREPCHAR: APOSTROPHE (~[\u0000-\u001F\u0027])*  APOSTROPHE;

QUOTEREPCHAR: QUOTE (~[\u0000-\u001F\u0022])*  QUOTE;

APOSTROPHE: '\'';

QUOTE: '"';

DOT: '.';

C: 'C';

// R603 name -> letter [alphanumeric-character]...
NAME: LETTER (ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER)*;

// R711 digit-string -> digit [digit]...
DIGITSTRING: DIGIT+; 

MINUS: '-';

B: 'B';

O: 'O';

Z: 'Z';

A: 'A';

F: 'F';

D: 'D';

E: 'E';

I: 'I';

G: 'G';

L: 'L';

DT: 'DT';

EN: 'EN';

ES: 'ES';

EX: 'EX';

T: 'T';

TL: 'TL';

TR: 'TR';

X: 'X';

SS: 'SS';

SP: 'SP';

S: 'S';

BN: 'BN';

BZ: 'BZ';

RU: 'RU';

RD: 'RD';

RZ: 'RZ';

RN: 'RN';

RC: 'RC';

RP: 'RP';

DC: 'DC';

DP: 'DP';

P: 'P';

// R602 UNDERSCORE -> _
UNDERSCORE: '_';

// R601 alphanumeric-character -> letter | digit | underscore
ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER: LETTER | DIGIT | UNDERSCORE;

// R0002 Letter ->
//         A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
//         N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z
LETTER: 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z'; 

// R0001 Digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
DIGIT: '0'..'9';

//PARSER RULES

programName: NAME;

// R1402 program-stmt -> PROGRAM program-name
programStmt: PROGRAM programName;

typeName: NAME;

// R516 keyword -> name
keyword: NAME;

// R863 implicit-stmt -> IMPLICIT implicit-spec-list | IMPLICIT NONE [( [implicit-name-spec-list] )]
implicitStmt:
        IMPLICIT NONE;

// R709 kind-param -> digit-string | scalar-int-constant-name
kindParam: DIGITSTRING;

// R708 int-literal-constant -> digit-string [_ kind-param]
intLiteralConstant: DIGITSTRING (UNDERSCORE kindParam)?;

// R712 sign -> + | -
sign: PLUS | MINUS;

// R707 signed-int-literal-constant -> [sign] int-literal-constant
signedIntLiteralConstant: sign? intLiteralConstant;

// R1306 r -> int-literal-constant
r: intLiteralConstant;

// R1308 w -> int-literal-constant
w: intLiteralConstant;

// R1309 m -> int-literal-constant
m: intLiteralConstant;

// R1310 d -> int-literal-constant
d: intLiteralConstant;

// R1311 e -> int-literal-constant
e: intLiteralConstant;

// R1312 v -> signed-int-literal-constant
v: signedIntLiteralConstant;

vList: v (COMMA v)*;

// R724 char-literal-constant -> [kind-param _] ' [rep-char]... ' | [kind-param _] " [rep-char]... "
charLiteralConstant: 
        (kindParam UNDERSCORE)? APOSTROPHEREPCHAR
    | (kindParam UNDERSCORE)? QUOTEREPCHAR;

// R1307 data-edit-desc ->
//         I w [. m] | B w [. m] | O w [. m] | Z w [. m] | F w . d |
//         E w . d [E e] | EN w . d [E e] | ES w . d [E e] | EX w . d [E e] |
//         G w [. d [E e]] | L w | A [w] | D w . d |
//         DT [char-literal-constant] [( v-list )]
dataEditDesc:
    I w (DOT m)? |
    B w (DOT m)? |
    O w (DOT m)? |
    Z w (DOT m)? |
    F w DOT d |
    E w DOT d ( E e )? |
    EN w DOT d ( E e )? |
    ES w DOT d ( E e )? |
    EX w DOT d ( E e )? |
    G w (DOT d ( E e )?)? |
    L w |
    A w? |
    D w DOT d |
    DT charLiteralConstant? ( LPAREN vList RPAREN )?;

// R1304 format-item ->
//         [r] data-edit-desc | control-edit-desc | char-string-edit-desc | [r] ( format-items )
formatItem: r? dataEditDesc;

// R1303 format-items -> format-item [[,] format-item]...
formatItems: formatItem (COMMA? formatItem)*;

// R1305 unlimited-format-item -> * ( format-items )
unlimitedFormatItem: ASTERIK LPAREN formatItems RPAREN;

// R1302 format-specification ->
//         ( [format-items] ) | ( [format-items ,] unlimited-format-item )
formatSpecification:
    LPAREN formatItems? RPAREN |  LPAREN (formatItems COMMA)? unlimitedFormatItem  RPAREN;

// R1301 format-stmt -> FORMAT format-specification
formatStmt: FORMAT formatSpecification;

//R506 implicit-part-stmt -> implicit-stmt | parameter-stmt | format-stmt | entry-stmt
implicitPartStmt:
      implicitStmt
    | formatStmt;

//R505 implicit-part -> [implicit-part-stmt]... implicit-stmt
implicitPart: (implicitPartStmt)* implicitStmt;

//R504 specification-part -> [use-stmt]... [import-stmt]... [implicit-part]
// [declaration-construct]...
  specificationPart:
    (implicitPart)?;

// R1403 end-program-stmt -> END [PROGRAM [program-name]]
endProgramStmt: END (PROGRAM programName?)?;

// R1401 main-program ->
//         [program-stmt] [specification-part] [execution-part]
//         [internal-subprogram-part] end-program-stmt
///COMMENT: WHY ? after programStmt
  mainProgram:
      programStmt? specificationPart? endProgramStmt;

//R502 program-unit -> main-program | external-subprogram | module | submodule | block-data
programUnit:
    mainProgram;

//R501 program -> program-unit [program-unit]...    
program: programUnit (programUnit)*;      

Test File: FortranTest.f90
FORMAT(I 12)

Commands:
antlr4 FortranTestF18.g4
javac *.java
grun FortranTestF18 formatStmt -tokens FortranTest.f90

Grun Output:
[@0,0:5='FORMAT',<FORMAT>,1:0]
[@1,6:6='(',<'('>,1:6]
[@2,7:7='I',<NAME>,1:7]
[@3,9:10='12',<DIGITSTRING>,1:9]
[@4,11:11=')',<')'>,1:11]
[@5,12:11='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:12]
line 1:7 no viable alternative at input '(I'

Here, token 'I' is recognized as NAME but I want it to be recognized as token I: 'I';. But if I move the lexer rule I to top of NAME then the identifiers cannot be named as 'I'. How do I solve this problem?

The FORMAT statements use its own micro-language. There should be some context switch.

The hacks most often used to perform the "context switch", which is suggested above, are Antlr lexer modes. When a FORMAT is found, switch modes for the input until a closing parenthesis is found. You would need to add code to pop immediately when FORMAT is not followed by an open parentheses. The current Fortran90 grammar does not work because the '/' literal is used in DIV and FORMATSEP. See https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/4096 for more details.

@kaby76 The linked thread is quite strange. It keeps talking about Fortan 90 but links to the specs of Fortran 2023. Those languages are extremely different, Fortran 2023 is much more complex and feature-rich compared to the ancient Fortran 90.

Here is the solution I implemented:
I divided the grammar into separate lexer and parser grammars and introduced lexer modes.
Parser Grammar: FortranTestF18Parser.g4
parser grammar FortranTestF18Parser;

options { tokenVocab = FortranTestF18Lexer; }


programName: NAME;

// R1402 program-stmt -> PROGRAM program-name
programStmt: PROGRAM programName;

typeName: NAME;

// R516 keyword -> name
keyword: NAME;

// R863 implicit-stmt -> IMPLICIT implicit-spec-list | IMPLICIT NONE [( [implicit-name-spec-list] )]
implicitStmt:
        IMPLICIT NONE;

// R709 kind-param -> digit-string | scalar-int-constant-name
kindParam: DIGITSTRING;

// R708 int-literal-constant -> digit-string [_ kind-param]
intLiteralConstant: DIGITSTRING (UNDERSCORE kindParam)?;

// R712 sign -> + | -
sign: PLUS | MINUS;

// R707 signed-int-literal-constant -> [sign] int-literal-constant
signedIntLiteralConstant: sign? intLiteralConstant;

// R1306 r -> int-literal-constant
r: intLiteralConstant;

// R1308 w -> int-literal-constant
w: intLiteralConstant;

// R1309 m -> int-literal-constant
m: intLiteralConstant;

// R1310 d -> int-literal-constant
d: intLiteralConstant;

// R1311 e -> int-literal-constant
e: intLiteralConstant;

// R1312 v -> signed-int-literal-constant
v: signedIntLiteralConstant;

vList: v (COMMA v)*;

// R724 char-literal-constant -> [kind-param _] ' [rep-char]... ' | [kind-param _] " [rep-char]... "
charLiteralConstant: 
        (kindParam UNDERSCORE)? APOSTROPHEREPCHAR
    | (kindParam UNDERSCORE)? QUOTEREPCHAR;

// R1307 data-edit-desc ->
//         I w [. m] | B w [. m] | O w [. m] | Z w [. m] | F w . d |
//         E w . d [E e] | EN w . d [E e] | ES w . d [E e] | EX w . d [E e] |
//         G w [. d [E e]] | L w | A [w] | D w . d |
//         DT [char-literal-constant] [( v-list )]
dataEditDesc:
    I w (DOT m)? |
    B w (DOT m)? |
    O w (DOT m)? |
    Z w (DOT m)? |
    F w DOT d |
    E w DOT d ( E e )? |
    EN w DOT d ( E e )? |
    ES w DOT d ( E e )? |
    EX w DOT d ( E e )? |
    G w (DOT d ( E e )?)? |
    L w |
    A w? |
    D w DOT d |
    DT charLiteralConstant? ( LPAREN vList RPAREN )?;

// R1304 format-item ->
//         [r] data-edit-desc | control-edit-desc | char-string-edit-desc | [r] ( format-items )
formatItem: r? dataEditDesc;

// R1303 format-items -> format-item [[,] format-item]...
formatItems: formatItem (COMMA? formatItem)*;

// R1305 unlimited-format-item -> * ( format-items )
unlimitedFormatItem: ASTERIK LPAREN formatItems RPAREN;

// R1302 format-specification ->
//         ( [format-items] ) | ( [format-items ,] unlimited-format-item )
formatSpecification:
  formatItems? |  (formatItems COMMA)? unlimitedFormatItem;

// R1301 format-stmt -> FORMAT format-specification
formatStmt: FORMATIN formatSpecification RPAREN;

//R506 implicit-part-stmt -> implicit-stmt | parameter-stmt | format-stmt | entry-stmt
implicitPartStmt:
      implicitStmt
    | formatStmt;

//R505 implicit-part -> [implicit-part-stmt]... implicit-stmt
implicitPart: (implicitPartStmt)* implicitStmt;

//R504 specification-part -> [use-stmt]... [import-stmt]... [implicit-part]
// [declaration-construct]...
  specificationPart:
    (implicitPart)?;

// R1403 end-program-stmt -> END [PROGRAM [program-name]]
endProgramStmt: END (PROGRAM programName?)?;

// R1401 main-program ->
//         [program-stmt] [specification-part] [execution-part]
//         [internal-subprogram-part] end-program-stmt
///COMMENT: WHY ? after programStmt
  mainProgram:
      programStmt? specificationPart? endProgramStmt;

//R502 program-unit -> main-program | external-subprogram | module | submodule | block-data
programUnit:
    mainProgram;

//R501 program -> program-unit [program-unit]...    
program: programUnit (programUnit)*;      

Lexer Grammar: FortranTestF18Lexer.g4
lexer grammar FortranTestF18Lexer;

options { caseInsensitive=true; }


LINE_COMMENT: '!' .*? '\r'? '\n' -> skip;

BLOCK_COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;

SPACE: [ ] -> skip;

WS: [\t\r\n]+ -> skip;

FORMATIN : FORMAT (SPACE)* LPAREN -> pushMode(FORMAT_MODE);

PROGRAM: 'PROGRAM';

END: 'END';

COMMA: ',';

LPAREN: '(';

RPAREN: ')';

ASTERIK: '*';

PLUS: '+';

MINUS: '-';

NONE: 'NONE';

IMPLICIT: 'IMPLICIT';

FORMAT: 'FORMAT';

DOT: '.';

APOSTROPHE: '\'';

QUOTE: '"';

// R602 UNDERSCORE -> _
UNDERSCORE: '_';

//R0003 RepChar
APOSTROPHEREPCHAR: APOSTROPHE (~[\u0000-\u001F])*?  APOSTROPHE;

QUOTEREPCHAR: QUOTE (~[\u0000-\u001F])*?  QUOTE;

// R603 name -> letter [alphanumeric-character]...
NAME: LETTER (ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER)*;

// R711 digit-string -> digit [digit]...
DIGITSTRING: DIGIT+; 

// R601 alphanumeric-character -> letter | digit | underscore
ALPHANUMERICCHARACTER: LETTER | DIGIT | UNDERSCORE;

// R0002 Letter ->
//         A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
//         N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z
LETTER: 'A'..'Z'; 

// R0001 Digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
DIGIT: '0'..'9';


///FORMAT MODE

mode FORMAT_MODE;

FORMAT_LPAREN: '(' -> pushMode(FORMAT_MODE), type(LPAREN);

FORMAT_RPAREN: ')' -> popMode, type(RPAREN);

FORMAT_SPACE: ' ' -> skip;

//R0003 RepChar
FORMAT_APOSTROPHEREPCHAR: FORMAT_APOSTROPHE (~[\u0000-\u001F\u0027])*?  FORMAT_APOSTROPHE -> type(APOSTROPHEREPCHAR);

FORMAT_QUOTEREPCHAR: FORMAT_QUOTE (~[\u0000-\u001F\u0022])*?  FORMAT_QUOTE -> type(QUOTEREPCHAR);

FORMAT_APOSTROPHE: '\'' -> type(APOSTROPHE);

FORMAT_QUOTE: '"' -> type(QUOTE);

FORMAT_PLUS: '+' -> type(PLUS);

FORMAT_MINUS: '-' -> type(MINUS);

FORMAT_COMMA: ',' -> type(COMMA);

FORMAT_ASTERIK: '*' -> type(ASTERIK);

FORMAT_DOT: '.' -> type(DOT);

// R711 digit-string -> digit [digit]...
FORMAT_DIGITSTRING: FORMAT_DIGIT+  -> type(DIGITSTRING); 

// R602 UNDERSCORE -> _
FORMAT_UNDERSCORE: '_' -> type(UNDERSCORE);

// R0001 Digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
FORMAT_DIGIT: '0'..'9' -> type(DIGIT);

I: 'I';

B: 'B';

O: 'O';

Z: 'Z';

F: 'F';

E: 'E';

EN: 'EN';

ES: 'ES';

EX: 'EX';

G: 'G';

L: 'L';

A: 'A';

D: 'D';

DT: 'DT';

By introducing a lexer mode for FORMAT statements and switching modes upon encountering FORMAT ( and exiting when ) is encountered, I was able to correctly classify tokens within the format context and resolve the misclassification issue.
